# Using multiple decorators to add functionality to an object?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to understand the decorator pattern and from the examples I understand how decorator objects can be used to extend existing functionality at runtime by overriding methods of the decorated object and how they add additional functionality via new method implementations.

Where I am getting a bit confused is where multiple decorators are used and how to access the extended functionality. Typically when looking at examples of the decorator pattern something like this is shown:

```
IBusinessObject businessObject = new MailDecorator(
    new SmsDecorator(
        new FaxDecorator(
            new BusinessObject()
        )
    )
);
```

the idea being to take an object and dynamically add mail, sms and fax functionaliy.
Now if you wanted to send a mail which is a method provided by the MailDecorator class you could do something like this:

```
If(businessObject is MailDecorator)
{
    ((MailDecorator) businessObject).SendMail();
}
```

However this would not work if you wanted to send an SMS or fax as in the normal implementation of the decorator pattern you will not have access to the object referenced by the decorator.

Is this a limitation of the decorator pattern or is it beyond the scope of what you can expect to achieve with this pattern or am I completely misunderstanding something here?
Would a different pattern be more appropriate?

The standard definition

> “Attach additional responsibilities to
>   an object dynamically. Decorators
>   provide a flexible alternative to
>   sub-classing for extending
>   functionality”

implies that this should be achievable with this pattern but appears to break down when using multiple decorators on one object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a common misconception of the decorator pattern. What you can do with the decorator pattern is to extend the **functionality**, not the **API**.

What does this mean?
It means, you can add new functionality, to the methods provided by the API, in your case `IBusinessObject`. Lets say your interface has a method `XmlDocument Export()` which is implemented in `BusinessObject` and returns the data in the `BusinessObject` instance in an `XmlDocument` instance.
Now, you could create a `LoggingDecorator`, which implements the `Export` method like so:

```
public XmlDocument Export()
{
    _logger.Log("Exporting...");
    var result = _decoratedObject.Export();
    _logger.Log("Done exporting...");
    return result;
}
```

Or you can create a `BusinessObjectSigningExportDecorator` which signs the returned `XmlDocument` using the xml-dsig algorithm:

```
public XmlDocument Export()
{
    var result = _decoratedObject.Export();
    return SignXmlDocument(result);
}
```

You could then use them together like so:

```
IBusinessObject businessObject = new LoggingDecorator(
    new BusinessObjectSigningExportDecorator(
        new BusinessObject()
    )
);

var xmlDocument = businessObject.Export();
```

The call to `Export` will now write the log messages and sign the xml export.
But you still can use `BusinessObject` without a decorator or with only one of the decorators.

The reason for using the decorator pattern is to be able to transparently add functionality. As you can see, the user of the `businessObject` variable of type `IBusinessObject` doesn't know and doesn't need to know the actual type that is used. It will work in the case with or without decorators.

Thinking further: When you have a factory that returns `IBusinessObject`s you can extend the functionality, without changing the code that uses them *and* without changing the implementation of the class the implement `IBusinessObject`. You just need to create another decorator and "attach" it inside the factory and therefore, you are making a change, that occurs only in a limited area of the code. So if this change breaks anything, you know exactly what code is responsible for the breakage.

Additionally, this enforces separation of concerns, because your normal business object implementation doesn't know and care about which signing algorithm should be used or that one needs to be used altogether.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i had a feeling the issue was more with my (mis)interpretation of the definition than with anything else. I like to allow a little time before accepting an answer but I think you've nailed the issue I was having with this concept.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for your response. Take your time.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: What can be used for extending the API in the way Andi wanted it to be?
E.g. i have an instance of class A. I want to create some objects that add some additional methods to this object (like b() and c() methods). What i want is to be able to add only b() method, only c() method or both of them (and possible make it at runtime). Is there any way i can achieve it?

Comment: @h8red: And how would you use the resulting object? I mean, with what type would you want to declare the variable of that object so you can access those methods without reflection?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: probably a new type (like A1 or smth like that). I just don't want to create 3 classes for b(), c() and both, because with more methods the amount of new classes is going to be huge.

Comment: @h8red: The big question here: How do you want to access the new methods? Do you have an interface or something? Mixins aren't really supported in C# and that's what you seem to be doing

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: oh, thanks for giving a name for the things i  tried to do. The interface + exntension method does what i actually want, but it doesnt look like an exammple of good code.

Comment: @h8red: I think extension methods are the accepted practice in C# to achieve simple Mixin behavior. I wouldn't necessarily call them bad code.

Comment: According to www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/designpatterns/VRQT130713-Decorator-Design-Pattern---C this is not true. A decorator may add new APIs. The Stream and FileStream is such an example. The FileStream has a Lock method that the abstract class Steam doesn't have.

Comment: @t3chb0t The main point of a decorator is that you still work with the original interface which gets transparently "enhanced" through the use of decorators - of which the user of the instance of the interface is unaware of. It doesn't affect him. Obviously, the decorator class can have additional members. But that is not part of the decorator pattern. It is simply possible, because the class is a class.