# how to solve this code duplication + add another method

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have 3 classes:

```
class First {
    public void SetA(){ ... }
    public void SetB(){ ... }
    public void SetC(){ ... }
    public void SetD(){ ... }
    public void SetZ(){ ... }
}

class Second {
    public void SetC(){ ... }
    public void SetD(){ ... }
    public void SetE(){ ... }
    public void SetF(){ ... }
    public void SetX(){ ... }
}

class Third{
    public void SetA(){ ... }
    public void SetB(){ ... }
    public void SetE(){ ... }
    public void SetF(){ ... }
    public void SetY(){ ... }
}
```

As you can see, I duplicate code in the same methods.
Yesterday I realized that sometimes I would like to add another commend inside each method.
So I am looking for a way to solve both those problems. One solution I thought about is:

1. Create Interface:

   ```
   interface IAllMethods {
           void SetA();
           void SetB();
           void SetC();
           void SetD();
           void SetE();
           void SetF();
           void SetX();
           void SetY();
           void SetZ();
   }
   ```
2. Create default implementation:

   ```
   class DefaultAllMethods {
           public void SetA(){ ... }
           public void SetB(){ ... }
           public void SetC(){ ... }
           public void SetD(){ ... }
           public void SetE(){ ... }
           public void SetF(){ ... }
           public void SetX(){ ... }
           public void SetY(){ ... }
           public void SetZ(){ ... }
   }
   ```
3. Create another implementation using decorator pattern in order to add the extra command:

   ```
   class ExtraAllMethods {
           private IAllMethods _allMethods;
           public ExtraAllMethods (IAllMethods allMethods) {
               _allMethods=allMethods;
           }
           public void SetA(){ 
               _allMethods.SetA();
               extraMethod();
           }
           public void SetB(){ 
               _allMethods.SetB();
               extraMethod();
           }
           public void SetC(){ 
               _allMethods.SetC();
               extraMethod();
           }
           ..
           ..
           ..
   }
   ```
4. Use the desire implementation inside classes First, Second and Third. For example:

   ```
   class Third{
       private IAllMethods  _allMethods;
       public Third(IAllMethods allMethods) {
           _allMethods=allMethods;
       }
       public void SetA(){ _allMethods.SetA(); }
       public void SetB(){ _allMethods.SetB(); }
       ..
       ..
       ..
   }
   ```

What do you think about this solution? Is there any better design to this need?

**UPDATE**
People ask for the real business, so here is it:
I have 3 types of transmission: TransmissionA, TransmissionB, TransmissionC
Each transmissions has many parameters (members or properties). For example, TransmissionA has WorkerId, CustomerId, MessageName and so on. TransmissionB has WorkerId and MessageName but no CustomerId. TransmissionC has WorkerId, CustomerId but no MessageName. These are example only - in my situation I have many more properties for each transmission. Each property has Set method.
Now there is a new need. Somewhere on the system there is an option called "Update Task". If the option is ON then I need to update relevant task in each Set method. This is why I thought on decorator pattern.

Comment: Why are you using methods instead of set properties?

Comment: Just declare an abstract class with the methods and inherit that class.  You can then simply override the method.  If the class doesn't use it then don't clall it or override it.

Comment: Are the classes actually interchangeable?  In other words, is it like a Dog and Cat that, although different, can both walk and bite?   I'm trying to understand exactly what it is they do and how they relate to each other.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan - I assume those methods actually do something.   I would agree its a poor design.

Comment: It would help if you explained what problem you're solving, instead of giving an abstraction and asking "how to make it more abstract". It allows us to help think outside the box.

Comment: What kind of data do these methods set? A property of the class? A generally kept boolean? Some value in a database. If it's the first, they can just be getters and setters.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't want unneeded methods on the classes. Moreover, sometimes I would like to use DefaultAllMethods and somethimes ExtraAllMethods.

Comment: @Chris Lively: The difference between dog and a cat is that there is a wolf also and dog knows to bark like the wolf and knows to sit just like the cat. Each knows other methods but not all.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: I added update for the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work but instead of introducing all-knowing interface and base implementation classes containing all methods (and thus having knowledge of the entirety of your collection of methods) you could also go for a more granular approach and just make a single interface and base implementation for each method. That would be more extensible and you could attach those just as easy in a plugin-like fashion if you set it up properly.

Comment: How can you imagine base implementation for each method with out multiple inheritance?

Comment: @mtijn: You mean that I should add 9 interfaces and implementation (in this example)?

Comment: yes and no, I was thinking of 9 interfaces and 9 classes with specific implementation, and I was thinking of your First, Second and Third classes implementing the interfaces they need by calling into the classes that have the actual interface implementation. Whether you want First, Second and Third to expose their functionality explicitly by inheritance or by keeping a public collection of the supported plugins is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

1. The interface is no good idea, because its implementors only provide functionality for a sub set of the methods provided by the interface.
2. The [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) can't be used here, because it is used to add functionality, it can't be used to change the API like adding methods. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551029/using-multiple-decorators-to-add-functionality-to-an-object/5551276#5551276) for more info.
3. If you have the same method with the same code in different classes, this should be extracted into its own class and used by the others. Currently, your classes most likely violate the [single responsible principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: 1. The interface is used here for the decorator. 2. I use the decorator in order to add extra command (like logging command) in each method and not for adding method. 3. Can you show me in this example how can I extracted the classes into one class?
4. There is no relation between same methods in other classes.

Comment: @Naor: As others have already pointed out: Your "example code" is not of much use, because it is to abstract. If you have the same code in different classes, this is a design flaw. How to solve it depends on your actual code base. About your answers: The decorator should implement the same interface as the decorated object, i.e. `First`, `Second` and `Third` should implement `IAllMethods`. This directly shows you that the interface is "wrong", because none of these three classes provide all methods of the interface. This also disqualifies the decorator approach as you showed it.

Comment: @Naor: To receive non-theoretical answers, provide actual code.

Comment: I know there is a gap - First, Second and Third will not implement IAllMethods. I am looking for better way. Other people suggested to create an interface for each property for example. Please look on the update I added.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what those methods are doing, so solutions could be different.
But if these methods are not tied one to an other somehow logically I would suggest to abstract each method by an interface like

```
    interface ILogicBAware
    {
      void DoB();
    }

    interface ILogicCAware
    {
      void DoC();
    }

    interface IAllMethods : ILogicBAware, ILogicCAware
    {
       void DoAll();
    }
```

In this way you get much flexibility and less coupling. In this way you can move forward and decide how actual logic will be encapsulated. But again it depends of what is under the hood of classes and methods you've provided...

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface for each single method and default implementation for each interface and make your classes implement only needed interfaces and be parameterized via constructor with default implementations to decorate.