# add log method to each setter

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture, entity-framework-4

I have 5 entities that are loaded using the entity framework. Here they are:
[image]
All of the entities are inherited from:
[image]

(Each entity represented by a class with the properties described above. Al entities inherit Transmission entity).
As you can see, there are common properties in some of the entities. But the properties WorkerId, WorkerPersonalId, VehicleId, VehicleNumber, SubcontractorId has special methods for SET so in order to encapsulate the logic of update I created WorkerVehicleTransmission class with those properties setters implementation. Each transmission now uses the WorkerVehicleTransmission.
Now I have a new need. I need to log each property change. For that I have the Log() method. For eaxmple, I need that when the user makes `cargoStorage.Weight=8;` there will be a call to Log() that will log this change.

Importent issue: I need to find a solution where the creation of an entity (by the entity framework for example) will not log.

How can I integrate the new need?

This question is the real need for the example I ask about here: [how to solve this code duplication + add another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984050/how-to-solve-this-code-duplication-add-another-method)

Comment: Adding logging to each property setter... sounds like a showcase for Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP)!

Comment: @stakx: Can you explain and give example how to do it?

Comment: No (otherwise, I would have posted a full answer), but I can give you some pointers. First, read up on the basic terminology of AOP, e.g. [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). Logging is a classic example of a "cross-cutting concern" which is often used to showcase AOP. So you could head over to e.g. [SharpCrafters](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), the creators of PostSharp (a popular AOP framework for .NET), and look for examples or at the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start you could attach a handler to the PropertyChanged event in the Transmission base class which will enable you to call the Log method whenever a property changes in any of your sub classes.

[INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)

This however will fire when any change is made, including when the Entity Framework creates the objects, so is only half way there.

---

**Edit**

<s>If you create a new property within the Transmission class (a boolean flag) you could use this in your data access object routines to set whether logging should be enabled.</s>

This flag is only ever set after any Entity Framework activity on each object has been completed therefore the only Property changes logged are those relating to your code.

Not an elegant solution but I cannot see any other way.

---

**Edit**

Just had a look at the EntityObject base members and there is an Property (Enumeration) named EntityState.

[EntityObject.EntityState Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.entitystate.aspx)

This property is set to "Detached" when the entity is being created (Unattached to the object context) by the Entity Framework and changes its value to "Added", "Deleted", "Modified" or "Unchanged" after it is added (depending on the state of the object).

By checking if the value is anything other than "Detached" you could then determine whether logging should be enabled.

Comment: Great! I actually can add to each Set call to notifyProperyChanged method and get by injection the class that holds the events code. But how can I detect when is the object created?..

Comment: Thanks, but the entity framework is just one possible to initialize the objects. What if I make new MyClass() {Prop1=1, Prop2=2}? What I am doing is: There will be 2 ways of setting each propery - 1. using the setter. 2. using the SetProperty methos. and the SetProperty will log. What do you think about this solution?