# Extension Methods - Decorator Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I was wondering if we can consider extension methods as an implementation of the decorator pattern in C#? as the aim is the same but logic of implementation as well as the conception may differ?

Thanks!

Comment: How are they at all similar to the decorator pattern? Extension methods are just syntactic sugar for calling static methods. Static methods being "plain old functions". A decorator is when you have an object extend the behaviour of another type of object by wrapping / delegating its methods or adding new ones.

Comment: I think this is a very good/valid question for a beginner. I'm not sure why the down-votes..

Comment: I think you miss understand something. Sure a extension mehtod "decorates" a type when you look at Intelisense. But, look at a good decorator implemention like the `StreamReader`. You noticed that is a derived class from `Stream` and really decorates the functionality of the Stream..

Comment: @CSharper Huh? `StreamReader` doesn't derive from `Stream`. Nor is that something that would make it a decorator. Quite the opposite fact. You use derived classes when you want to extend the behaviour of new instances of the base class. You use a decorator when you want to change the behaviour of a specific, already existing instance of the decorated class. (If that makes sense, I'm not sure how to phrase this right.)

Comment: @CSharper Or, to borrow from wikipedia: subclassing changes behaviour at compile-time, decorating changes behaviour at runtime.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Sure. The `StreamReader` does not derive from the `Stream`. But if I use the `StreamReader`that takes a `Stream` in his constr. it decorates the underlying `Stream`?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The decorator pattern is usually associated with adding behavior to particular instances of a type independently of other instances.  In the case of an extension method it affects all instances of a type which are compiled in the same scope.  I'd argue that it's not a part of the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 9):

I think you didn't understand the decorator pattern correctly.
It is not about adding *new methods*. It's about adding new functionality to *existing methods*.

So, no, Extension methods are not an implementation of the decorator pattern.

Comment: i see now , but is there a concret implementation of the decorator in .NET not hidden in some library we ever use?

Comment: I currently don't know any off the top of my head, but if you are looking for an example, you can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5551276/572644). I used a concrete one when explaining the pattern.