# Is there a pattern to inherit from a not visible class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, obfuscation, decorator

To visualize my problem, here a little picture:

[image: The problem]

We have here two assemblies. Both of them are obfuscated. The base is written and obfuscated by us. The special one is written and obfuscated by an other person A. A does not have our sources and we do not have his. The whole idea is, that A wants to be able to extend every function in our `BaseAssembly`. A knows that we have implementations for all public visible interfaces in the `BaseInterfaceAssembly`. He wants to extend our `BaseClass` by adding `methodB()` and doing something in `methodA()` before the base implementation is called. `BaseClass` is internal and obfuscated.

This is the point where the decorator comes in play. We could force A to make a decorator for an `BaseInterface` object. For this we would need make an abstract decorator base where A only needs to override `methodA()` and add `methodB()`. For him there would be no difference. For us,we have to write and maintain these abstract decorators for every interface. This is an overhead we do not want.

First question, is there an alternative where both sides do not have an overhead - I would also accept some kind of hack, if it does not produce performance issues after the object creation?

Second question, if there is no alternative, is there a way to write one abstract decorator of all interfaces that are there and that will be there in the future?

**EDIT**

As requested some sample code:

```
public interface BaseInterface
{
    void MethodA();
}

internal class BaseClass : BaseInterface
{
    public virtual void MethodA()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

internal class SpecialClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void MethodA()
    {
        //do something before
        base.MethodA();
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Regards, Yggdrasil

Comment: "For this we would need make an abstract decorator base", why we? why not place the responsibility of writing the decorator + dec.base by the implementor of the decorator? Who controls instanciation?

Comment: Nice quesiton! Maybe you can create a wrapper with Interop calls. Can you post some code please or Just like Extention Methods in C# it is also applying Decorater pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211385/extension-methods-decorator-pattern

Comment: Thx for the advice so far. I have added some sample code. For the extension methods, they work for extending `MethodB()`, but I does not work for manipulating `MethodA()` as shown in the sample code.