# abstracting an interface to a class that has extension methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

How do I replace a concrete class with its interface for the purpose of unit testing if I am using extension methods in that class?

I've got a method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/yoyo/{yoyoId:int}/accounts")]
public ResponseYoyoEnvelope GetAccountsByYoyoId([FromBody] RequestYoyoEnvelope requestYoyoEnvelope, int yoyoId)
{
    var responseYoyoEnvelope = requestYoyoEnvelope.ToResponseYoyoEnvelope();

    // get our list of accounts
    // responseEnvelope.Data = //list of accounts
    return responseYoyoEnvelope;
}
```

I'd like to replace:

```
RequestYoyoEnvelope requestYoyoEnvelope
```

with an abstraction:

```
IRequestYoyoEnvelope requestYoyoEnvelope
```

however, `ToResponseYoyoEnvelope` is an extension method.

How do I replace a concrete class with its interface for the purpose of unit testing if I am using extension methods in that class?

Answer (score 4):

You can write the extension method against the interface rather than the concrete class:

```
public static class Class2
{
    public static void Extension(this ITestInterface test)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("This is allowed");
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
// "Test" is some class that implements the ITestInterface interface
ITestInterface useExtensionMethod = new Test();
useExtensionMethod.Extension();
```

Note too that this'll still work even if `useExtensionMethod` isn't explicitly of type `ITestInterface`:

```
Test useExtensionMethod = new Test();
useExtensionMethod.Extension();
```

There's [controversy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211385/extension-methods-decorator-pattern) about whether this represents a Decorator pattern but keep in mind at a minimum that the Extension method isn't literally a part of the interface itself - [it's still a static method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) "under the hood," it's just that the compiler's allowing you the convenience of treating this like an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
public class RequestYoyoEnvelope : IRequestYoyoEnvelope { ... }
```

Your extension method would need to target the interface

```
public static ResponseYoyoEnvelope ToResponseYoyoEnvelope(this IRequestYoyoEnvelope target) { ... }
```

Keep the action as is because the model binder will have issues binding the interface.

In your unit test you pass a concrete implementation of `RequestYoyoEnvelope` and the updated extension method should be able to be tested.

From your example you would not need an interface to test if that method is the method under test. just new up an instance of the model and pass it to the method during the unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAccountsByYoyoIdTest() {
    //Arrange
    var controller = new YoyoController();
    var yoyoId = 123456;
    var model = new RequestYoyoEnvelope {
        //you populate properties for test
    };
    //Act
    var result = controller.GetAccountsByYoyoId(model, yoyoId);

    //Assert
    //...do your assertions.
}
```

Comment: I adjusted my answer once I realized what I had missed - that this is an API endpoint. Then I read this answer - @Nkosi didn't miss it and this answer is much more on-point.